# How do you type @ on a French Canadian keyboard

Tags: networking

How do you type @ on a French Canadian keyboard

Comment: Are you asking specifically on Ubuntu? Normally it's Alt+2.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `AltGr-0` as reported in this [Wikipedia article on AZERTY layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY). Or if that doesn't work try `AltGr-2`, It's for Canadian French [QWERTY based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Canadian_Multilingual_Standard)

Comment: Yes, installing French canadian layout shows me that: @ is on alt+2

Comment: Please don't confuse `Alt` and `AltGr`.   They are not exactly the same.  AltGr is there where on US Keyboards, is the right Alt key.  It is specifically used to generate "special" characters and is very common on European keyboards.  Hitting Left-Alt will not work. Read all about it on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key

Comment: Answers should be correct at the time of writing, and not include a potential answer, then an 'Ah no' and *another* possible answer. You could cheer this answer up by [edit]ing it to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

In gnome-shell (Gnome 3) you can view currently using layout's [hereimage/map/blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JdFt.png) to see exactly where all symbols are located.

Go to settings->keyboard->input sources->select your layout->  [click on keyboard icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKLzy.png) and it will pop out.

Even faster just click `Show Keyboard Layout` under layout chooser in gnome's top bar if there is.